# Docker- Giving Container access to Host's CA certs

Tags: security, docker, certificate, certificate-authority

I was wondering security wise if there was anything wrong with volume mounting the host's ca certs into a container. I.e,

```
docker run \
    -v /usr/local/share/ca-certificates:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates:ro \
    image:tag
```

I want to avoid the typical process of copying in a file and running `update-ca-certificates` for the container, and the host is already setup like this. Anything wrong with this? Is there a better way?

Deployment constraints:

- Using ootb provided containers that I don't want to make my own version of just to throw in a few files (also not feasibe in my use case)
- Running from just `docker run` command, no `compose`

Comment: The ca certs for the container might be different than the container. In terms of the security principle of lateral movement i would stay away from it, if the container gets compromised, they don't have the ca certs of the host. Im wondering what's yow use case for it

Comment: @Turdie What security risk? The CA certificates tells whom *you* trust, they do not enable someone to issue certificates.

Comment: Do you know the concept of lateral movement? If a threat actor comprises container he might be able to easier compromise the host or a workload running on the host using the ca certs

Comment: I note that in my code example I have the mounted directory readonly, which was deliberate for this reason

Answer (score 1):

> Anything wrong with this?

No - as long as you want to trust the same sets of CA's, there should be no problem with mounting this read only in the container.

Depending on the distro in the Docker image you may have to run a command such as `update-ca-certificates` to make the system aware of the certificates. This would, I believe, apply to e.g. Ubuntu and Debian.